# FreeRTOS Select with TCP sockets unavailable?

Tags: c, sockets, select, freertos, lwip

### Context

A standard practice for managing multiple socket connections is use `poll` or `select`. This allows the calling thread (or task, in this case) to block until the operating system detects that data is available to read (at which point it resumes the task)

### Problem

In FreeRTOS, the system API provides a mechanism for this called [FreeRTOS_select](https://www.freertos.org/FreeRTOS-Plus/FreeRTOS_Plus_UDP/API/select.html). However, the documentation specifies:

1. `FreeRTOS_select` takes a socket-set of type `xSocketSet_t` (see link above) which contains sockets of type `xSocket`.
2. `xSocket` is created with [FreeRTOS_socket](https://www.freertos.org/FreeRTOS-Plus/FreeRTOS_Plus_UDP/API/socket.html).
3. The documentation for `FreeRTOS_socket` states that `xType` (socket type) quote: "Must be set to FREERTOS_SOCK_DGRAM" (see link above).

If you can only create datagram sockets, you can't use this select call with stream sockets. When searching for creating stream sockets, I found that an identical call to `FreeRTOS_socket` [here](https://www.freertos.org/FreeRTOS-Plus/FreeRTOS_Plus_TCP/API/socket.html) in the example. However, this is for something called "FreeRTOS + TCP" and the API doesn't have an example for `select`. The type of the socket returned is not `xSocket_t` but `Socket_t`.

---

So how can you use select with TCP sockets? There doesn't seem to be a straightforward answer anywhere about this. The problem I have is that I would like to use the built in `select` functions of FreeRTOS because they can automatically manage the task for me. Using a library-based select may not be possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like I was wrong, there is a dedicated `FreeRTOS_select` call for select with TCP too available at [this link](https://www.freertos.org/FreeRTOS-Plus/FreeRTOS_Plus_TCP/API/select.html). It's just difficult to locate. This is my fault for not spending enough time trying to find the API calls using other means.